# How to avoid warning message while using gedit?

Tags: 11.04, gedit

How to avoid the following warning message from gedit(2.30.4) on Ubuntu 11.04.

```
(gedit:25519): CRITICAL **: gedit_spell_checker_language_to_key: assertion `lang != NULL' failed
```

Comment: apparently those messages mean nothing, as gedit works like usual.

Comment: Of course, I am able to use gedit but the warning messages are filling the terminal from where gedit was lanched. Moreover, I think that it would be good if we know the reasons behind the messages.

Answer (score 3):

assuming you start gedit in the shell you could pipe all output to null, as in

`gedit textfile.txt > /dev/null 2>&1 &`

and maybe create a shell script with $@ instead of textfile.txt to allow general filenames, i.e. create a file, say `geditt` with the following contents:

```
gedit &@ > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

save it in your path -- maybe `~/bin` -- and make it executable via `chmod +x ~/bin/geditt`

Comment: Thanks. But it would be good if we know the reasons behind the warnings.

Comment: you could file a bug or ask a question at https://launchpad.net/gedit